# Strategies for keeping and locking messages in a queue with one consumer hiding multiple users

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am trying to implement the following scenario and I could really use and appreciate some help. I am using ActiveMQ 5.14 with camel 2.21.

In the queue, each message corresponds to a single machine. The machines connect to the queue through a single polling consumer and are indistinguishable to the consumer. The messages should be kept in the queue until one machine acknowledges that it has reached the correct machine via a separate request. After each fetch of a message said message should be locked for a certain time.

I could not find any ActiveMQ functionality that translates to my problem. My approach would be to send the message after each fetch to a second queue, which serves as a lock mechanism and send it back to the fetchable queue after the specified timeout.
Maybe a better approach would be to rollback the session after each fetch if the message has not been acknowledged by the machine.

Do you have any suggestions what a viable solution to this problem would look like?

**edit:** more details to clarify the situation

The application communicates to the clients via exposing a REST API to the web with two calls: **GET** and **DELETE**.
GET fetches the next message from the queue and DELETE deletes the message from the queue. I need to make sure that a message is only fetched once in a given time period and that it makes its way back to the queue if the client doesn't send a DELETE request. Currently I have a route from the rest service to a bean which fetches a message from the queue returns it to the GET request and sends it back to the queue after. On a DELETE request I dequeue the message from the queue with the given id.
I still need to find a way to ensure that the last fetched message cant be accessed for a specified time period.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "should be locked for a certain time"?

Comment: @cosmos I need to ensure that the message is only being processed by one recipient for a given amount of time, after that it can be requeued and be made available to the next recipient again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a bit confused about the part with the indistinguishable machines, but I understood the following:

- You have 1 queue with messages
- You have 1 consumer
- The consumer takes a message and calls a service or similar
- If the call is successful the message can be deleted
- If the call fails the message must be reprocessed

If these assumptions are correct, you can build a Camel route that consumes messages from the queue (**transacted**) and calls the service.

- If the Camel **route fails** to complete (service returns error) and the error is **not** handled, the broker does a rollback and the **message is redelivered** (immediately)
- If the route fails multiple times (when max redelivery value is reached), the message is sent to the **dead letter queue** (by the broker) to move it out of the way but save it
- If the **route succeeds** the message consumption is committed to the broker and the **message deleted**
- In such a setup you could also configure more consumers to process the messages in parallel (if the called service allows this)

This behaviour is more or less the default behaviour if

- Your broker is configured as persistent (avoid message loss)
- You consume messages transacted (a local transaction with the broker is enough)
- Camel does **not** handle the errors (when they are handled, the message is committed because the broker does not "see" any error)
- You get an error from the service or you can at least decide if there was a problem and throw the error yourself. The broker must get an Exception so that a rollback is done

**EDIT**

Based on your clarification I understand that it is the other way round than I assumed.

Well then I would probably see the two request types as "workflow steps" since they are triggered from the clients.

**GET**

- Consume a message, send it to requestor
- Add a timestamp to the message header
- Send the message to **another queue** (let's call it `delievered`)

**DELETE**

- Dequeue the message from the `delievered` queue

**Not deleted messages**

- Use the timestamp header and [message selectors](http://activemq.apache.org/selectors.html) to consume not deleted messages after a certain amount of time
- Move them back to the source queue

With a second queue you have various advantages

- Messages in processing cannot be consumed again and therefore need no "lock"
- The source queue contains only waiting messages, the `delievered` queue only messages in processing
- You could increase message priority when sending not deleted messages back to the source queue so they are re-consumed fast
- You could also add a counter header when sending not deleted messages back to the source queue to identify messages that are failed multiple times and process them in another way.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to clarify the situation:
The application exposes a REST API to the web, which listens to two calls GET and DELETE. GET fetches the next message from the queue and DELETE deletes the message from the queue.
I need to make sure that a message is only fetched once in a given time period and that it makes its way back to the queue if the client doesn't send a DELETE request.
Currently I am sending the message back to the queue after it was fetched and dequeue it on a delete request, but I don't know what a good solution to this situation, using ActiveMQ tools would be.

Comment: I have extended my answer based on your clarification